# Spark SVM Model

Tags: apache-spark, model, svm

In Spark SVM algorithm we have code like below

```
SVMWithSGD svm=new SVMWithSGD();
  int numIterations=200;
  model=svm.train(parsedData.rdd(),numIterations)
```

I want to know, what does model look like? for example what are its features and what is the sort of features in the model?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract model by checking:

- `intercept` - intercept.
- `weights` - weights of features